# API in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8

I'm working with API on a laravel-8 project. But I am totally confused with how the API works. What is the difference between `web.php` and `api.php`? How to do authentication check with API. And also how to show the output of API (i.e) As a `view` or just as a `JSON or raw output`. I've never worked with APIs and I'm new to laravel as well.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x).

The difference between those two files is described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-routes-directory):

> The web.php file contains routes that the RouteServiceProvider places
> in the web middleware group, which provides session state, CSRF
> protection, and cookie encryption. If your application does not offer
> a stateless, RESTful API, all of your routes will most likely be
> defined in the web.php file
>
> The api.php file contains routes that the RouteServiceProvider places
> in the api middleware group, which provides rate limiting. These
> routes are intended to be stateless, so requests entering the
> application through these routes are intended to be authenticated via
> tokens and will not have access to session state.

Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication) part of the docs to learn about authentication.

What an API returns depends on the use case. Could be JSON/XML/etc., could be HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The api file can do exactly what the web file can do. You can see this in the `RouteServiceProvider`.

The only difference is: the prefix and middleware.

Please read the documentation.

The difference between those two files is described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-routes-directory).

Answer (score 0):

The `web.php` is used for your `normal web applications routes`.For instance if you have a home page and an about us page this is where you will write their routes.

For the `api.php`, this is where you defined `routes that other devices other` than your web application can communicate with your app.